# Using the same USB device with two apps on Android

Tags: android, usb, intentfilter

I have developed two applications that use USB host. The second application mimics the functionality of the first, its just slightly different for testing purposes.
 The first application works with USB perfectly, but the second one never asks the user for permission and therefore USB doesn't work. I've checked the manifests and I cant see a problem.

Surely two apps can use the same USB device independently?

Will post code if needed - thanks